# Merge documentation tags jQuery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Tags: support, documentation, tag-alias-request

The [jquery-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery-selectors/topics) tag is already a topic in the [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/389/selectors) tag, so it would make sense for these to not be separate.

I think that [jquery-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery-plugins/topics) will either be way too broad, trying to cover the scope of all plugins for jQuery, which is a lot. I think it could potentially go in as a topic in jQuery and it could highlight some of the larger plugins. Currently it appears to just be covering how to develop plugins in jQuery, and only has basic examples of functions.

Also, I'm not sure it make sense to have a [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery-mobile/topics) tag as well, because I feel like most topics in it will either relate to jquery itself, or mobile design.

Comment: I think it makes sense to merge these. However, dealing with the same tag duplication at that point may be difficult.